# rails scope for find children count in has_many

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby on Rails application I have two models:

```
class CuratorGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :art_objects, join_table: "curator_groups_art_objects"
end

class ArtObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :currently_displayed, -> { where(status: "Currently On Display") }
  has_and_belongs_to_many :curator_groups, join_table: "curator_groups_art_objects"
end
```

No I want to write a scope that returns me all Curator groups that have at least one art object?
How can I do this?

Comment: Out of the curiosity - doesn't simple `CuratorGroup.joins(:art_objects)` work?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Have tried with a similar association on my own project. I'm hoping I've translated it to your project without typos.

```
CuratorGroup.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN curator_groups_art_objects ON curator_groups_art_objects.curator_group_id = curator_groups.id').group('curator_groups.id').having('count(curator_groups_art_objects.curator_group_id) > 0').all
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But now I want to add another clause to having. To find only curator_groups which have at lease one art_object with status = "Test". Thanks in advance.

Comment: I try something like this but not works:
CuratorGroup.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN curator_groups_art_objects ON curator_groups_art_objects.curator_group_id = curator_groups.id').group('curator?', 'test').having('count(curator_groups_art_objects.curator_group_id) > 0').all

Comment: Put a where clause on the end. `CuratorGroup.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN curator_groups_art_objects ON curator_groups_art_objects.curator_group_id = curator_groups.id').group('curator_groups.id').having('count(curator_groups_art_objects.curator_group_id) > 0').where(status: "Test").all`

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply but this code that you write in comment looking for curator_group which status is Test but I want to find curator_groups which have at least one art_object which art_object status is Test.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
scope :has_art, -> { :includes => :art_objects, :conditions => { "curator_groups_art_objects.art_object_id != nil"} }
```